# Joining 4 tables based on id and dates

Tags: sql, powerbi, tableau-desktop

I have to join 2 tables in order to find out the Products that have Stock in danger to expire based on current orders.

*Each product can have multiple stock locations, 
*Each product can have multiple orders/day, 
*One Product can be present in the Stock_table and absent from Orders_table & vice versa or present in both tables

```
Stock_table 
ProductID(VARCHAR) |StockLocation(VARCHAR) |Stock(NUMBER) |Stock_Expiration_Date(DATE-YYYY-MM-DD)
Meatballs          |Warehouse              | 100          |2022-04-01
Meatballs          |Fridge                 | 10           |2022-04-21 
Milk               |Fridge                 | 5            |2021-12-24
```

```
Orders_table
ProductID(VARCHAR) | Order_ID(VARCHAR)     | Quantity(NUMBER)  | Order_Date(DATE-YYYY-MM-DD)
Meatballs          | x1                    | 50                | 2022-01-19
Meatballs          | x2                    | 200               | 2023-09-22   
Milk               | x1                    | 100               | 2021-10-22
```

60(110-50) meatballs will expire before the next order;

What have i tried:

Created a Product table with the unique values from Stock_Table and Orders_Table (Union and drop duplicates)

```
Product_Table
ProductID(VARCHAR)
Meatballs
Milk
```

Joined the Product_Table to the Stock_Table and Orders_Table based on ProductID with a left join
on 
Product_Table.ProductID = Stock_Table.ProductID 
and 
Product_Table.ProductID = Orders_Table.ProductID

Created a Calendar table with the unique date values from Stock_Table and Orders_Table

```
Calendar_Table
Date_id
2022-04-01
2022-04-21 
2021-12-24
2022-01-19
2023-09-22
2021-10-22
```

Got stuck here..